# CallBack is not working in Node Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, request

I am trying so hard to make this work but I can't.

This function is inside of a **router.get function**. My front end app makes me a call and I request other service. 
In this service I get info about the parent folder. After this I make a foreach *( localProjects.forEach)* to get the info folders, this call back is working pretty well but when I send ***projects:localProjects*** the hours still being in 0 zero. I print the hours but for some reason hours still being in zero.

```
request.get('/folders/'+parentFolder+'/folders?descendants=false&project=false', {
    'auth': {
        'bearer': Token
    }
}, function(err, response, body) {
    var folders = JSON.parse(body);
    //console.log(folders);
    folders.data.forEach(function (folder) {
        localProjects.push({id: folder.id, name: folder.title, hours: 0})
    });
    // console.log(localProjects)
    localProjects.forEach(function(folder, index){
        getFolderHours(folder,{start:start, end:end}, function (hours) {
            console.log('Total hrs:'+ hours)
            localProjects[index].hours = hours;
        })
    }); //end localprojects
    console.log('responding')
    res.send({totalHours: totalHours, projects:localProjects});
}); // end request timelog
```

My call back function is the following

```
var getFolderHours = function (folder,period, callback) {
    request.get('folders/'+folder.id+'/timelogs?trackedDate={"start":"'+period.start+'T00:00:00","end":"'+period.end+'T23:59:59"}',{
        'auth': {
            'bearer':Token
        }
    }, function (err, response, body){
        var timelog = JSON.parse(body);
        var hours = 0 ;
        if (! err){
            console.log('Name:'+ folder.name);
            console.log('Hrs:'+ folder.hours);
            // console.log('Id:'+ folder.id);
            timelog.data.forEach(function (task) {
                console.log('Adding:'+ task.hours);
                hours += task.hours
            });
            callback(hours)
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not work because you are sending the request before getFolderHours finish executing. This is because `getFolderHours` is async, so you have to make of its operations in `localProjects` for loop finish executing.

What I would do is wrap `getFolderHours` in a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object and resolve them all once the `localProjects` finish looping. If you are not familiar yet with Promises, I suggest you read up the link on Promise I have provided. So your code would look something like the following:

```js
request.get('/folders/'+parentFolder+'/folders?descendants=false&project=false', {
    'auth': {
        'bearer': Token
    }
}, function(err, response, body) {
    var folders = JSON.parse(body);
    var localProjectsResolved = [];
    //console.log(folders);
    folders.data.forEach(function (folder) {
        localProjects.push({id: folder.id, name: folder.title, hours: 0})
    });
    // console.log(localProjects)
    localProjects.forEach(function(folder, index){
        var currentFolderHours = getFolderHours(folder,{start:start, end:end}, function (hours) {
            console.log('Total hrs:'+ hours)
            localProjects[index].hours = hours;
        });
        localProjectsResolved.push(currentFolderHours);
    }); //end localprojects
    console.log('responding');
  // resolve all localprojects
  Promise.all(localProjectsResolved).then(function(localProjectResults) {
      // got the results, send the request
      res.send({totalHours: totalHours, projects:localProjectResults});
    });
}); // end request timelog

// wrap getFolderHours in promise
function getFolderHours(folder,period) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request.get('folders/'+folder.id+'/timelogs?trackedDate={"start":"'+period.start+'T00:00:00","end":"'+period.end+'T23:59:59"}',{
          'auth': {
              'bearer':Token
          }
      }, function (err, response, body){
          var timelog = JSON.parse(body);
          var hours = 0 ;
          if (!err){
              console.log('Name:'+ folder.name);
              console.log('Hrs:'+ folder.hours);
              // console.log('Id:'+ folder.id);
              timelog.data.forEach(function (task) {
                  console.log('Adding:'+ task.hours);
                  hours += task.hours
              });
              // resolve the number of hours
              resolve(hours);
          } else {
            reject(err);
          }
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: that was awesome Dude !!. I have been reading about promises, I thought I can do this just with callbacks. I am starting with node js and I want to follow best practices but I guess I need more experience and read more. Thanks, Dude any tip is welcome. I really appreciated your help

Comment: I really recommend nodejs design patterns 2nd edition and work through the examples.